# Kotlin Console Application in IntelliJ 2021.2.3 -> Cannot add main class "MainKt" in Run/Debug configuration

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have created a new Kotlin Console Application in IntelliJ using Project JDK openjdk.17.

I have changed the gradle version to 7.3 in the file gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

When I create a Kotlin Console Application project in IntelliJ it creates a file named "Main.kt". The file is not a class, but a function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

On one of my computers at home I can run the program by clicking the Run button (SHIFT+F10) in IntelliJ. On another computer with the same setup the Run button is grey. Here I need to add a Run/Debug Configuration.

In "Run/Debug Configuration" I select + then Kotlin. In Main class I cannot select "MainKt".

What I have tried:

- Invalid cache/Restart
- Create new project, but I get the same problem

My source code:

**src\main\kotlin\Main.kt:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")

    // Try adding program arguments via Run/Debug configuration.
    // Learn more about running applications: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html.
    println("Program arguments: ${args.joinToString()}")
}
```

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    application
}

group = "me.admin"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
kotlin.code.style=official
```

**settings.gradle.kts:**

```
rootProject.name = "untitled"
```

**gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: What version of IDE and OS do you use? Are there any related exceptions in IDE logs?

Comment: I use IntelliJ Idea 2021.2.3 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging I found out that I could make a run configuration file manually by creating a directory and a XML file.

**.run/MainKt.run:**

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="MainKt" type="JetRunConfigurationType" nameIsGenerated="true">
    <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="MainKt" />
    <module name="untitled.main" />
    <shortenClasspath name="NONE" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>
```

You can change *untitled.main* with the name of your project.